# How should I use Mole Amarillo Powder?

Tags: sauce, spices, mexican-cuisine

On a recent trip to Oaxaca, Mexico, I bought an unlabelled bag of [mole amarillo](https://www.mexicoinmykitchen.com/mole-amarillo-recipe/) (yellow mole) powder from a spice vendor.  I neglected to ask them how it should be used in recipes.  While I'm used to working with mole negro paste, this is the first time I've dealt with a powdered mole.  Also, the resulting consistency for mole amarillo is different from mole negro or coloradito -- it's more souplike.

I'm not sure how to use this in a recipe.  Among my questions are:

- How much powder should I use for one 2-3L pot?
- Should I use water or stock?
- How much water/stock should I add to the powder?
- Do I boil it before adding any meat/vegetables to the mole, or do I just use it right away?  If I cook it first, for how long?

I've looked up [some commercially](https://spicesinc.com/blends-and-rubs/mexican-mole-powder) [available](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08L9TQNFV) [mole amarillo](https://woodlandfoods.com/products/oaxacan-mole-amarillo-starter/c-23/p-19375) [powders online](https://www.soyoaxaca.com/us/products/mole-amarillo-powder-rysdo/), but they all have rather vague instructions, and none are consistent with each other.  Any experienced advice, from someone who has actually used one?

Answer (score 1):

I have found (through my own experimentation) that:

Use *about* the same volume of powder as water or stock.

Water *or* stock can be used.

Flavor is less assertive than mole negro, so milder dishes - shrimp, not carne asada ....

But I could be wrong on any if these. If so, let me know at hkerfoot_at_gmail.com. I was just gifted 2 500-gram bags of powder!

Comment: So 1 cup water, 1 cup mole amarillo powder?  Loosely packed, I assume?